# Intellij Idea Keyboard Shortcut To Select A Token

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any intellij idea shortcut to select a token in a statement?

For example, consider this:

```
cell.setCellValue((profileInfo.get("startTimeOfCrawl")!=null)?profileInfo.get("startTimeOfCrawl"):"");
```

Currently, if my cursor is on the first character of the above statement(i.e. at beginning of `c` of `cell`, if I have to select `profileInfo`, then I will have to use my mouse and double click on `profileInfo` to select that.

Another workaround I found was to use arrow keys to get cursor to `profileInfo`
Then use ctrl+shift+right-arrow keys to select till the end(i.e. till o) of `profileInfo`
This is good when my cursor is placed at beginning of `profileInfo`(or even end in which case we can use left-arrow key). 
But if my cursor is placed somewhere in between of `profileInfo` then I will have to use ctrl+right (or ctrl+left) to get the cursor to either beginning or end of this token. Then I Will have to use ctrl+shift+right-arrow (or left-arrow as the case may be).

(Switching from keyboard to mouse breaks the continuity, hence looking for keyboard shortcuts.)

Is there a better shortcut to do above in 1 step?

PS: Solution to above will be very useful when making string replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Use Edit | Extend Selection (Ctrl-W in the default keymaps, Alt-Up in the Mac OS 10.5+ keymap). You can press it multiple times to extend the selection to larger enclosing syntax constructs.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a 1-step process of doing this but try using the <kbd>alt</kbd> to traverse via arrow keys, it will traverse it per "word" instead of per character.

You can also use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> to select per word.

Comment: Using alt with arrows to traverse switches tabs for me in intellij idea 14.0.3
Are you using default intellij keymap?

Comment: yep default, sorry forgot to mention I'm on Mac.